# DragableBottomSheet with reverse PageListView

Tags: flutter

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
              maxChildSize: 1,
              initialChildSize: 1,
              minChildSize: 0,
              expand: false,
              builder: (context, scrollController) =>
                  Comment(product: productDto, controller: scrollController)),

PagedListView.separated(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.w),
                        reverse: !_isScroll,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollController: widget.controller,
                        dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
                        builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<CommentDto>(
                          itemBuilder: (context, commentDto, index) {
                            return ItemComment(
                              commentDto: commentDto,
                              isShowInModal: true,
                            );
                          },
```

The Comment widget is the PagedListView. is there anyway I can seperate the 'reverse' in the PageListView and DraggableScrollSheet?, like the list comment of Facebook. I want the latest comments is at the bottom, so I use reverse, but when I use that, the DraggableScrollSheet have to swipe up to close, not swipe down at the top of the page.

I have tried to set the reverse is false when the Scroll start, but it doesn't take effect.